# Excel Charts Hexadecimal axis values

Tags: excel, excel-charts

I have `Hexadecimal` values exported as `decimal` in an excel sheet (to support chart plotting).

Now, when i plot those values , in the chart's axis i get decimal values. Instead i want hexadecimal values to be shown as axis values..

[image]

How can i format the axis to show Hexadecimal values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn off the vertical axis labels and use data labels to make your own (step-by-step below):

[image]

**Step 1.** Select the bar chart data and create a new bar chart. Format the color.

**Step 2.** Select the horizontal axis. Under Format Axis > AXIS OPTIONS > Axis Type, select "Text axis".

[image]

**Step 3.** Select the vertical axis. Under Format Axis > LABELS > Label Position, select "None".

**Step 4.** Right-click the chart. Select "Select Data", then add a new series. Select the series values. Click "OK".

**Step 5.** Right-click the newly added series. Select "Change Series Chart Type".

[image]

Change the newly added series to "Scatter with Straight Lines" and check the "Secondary Axis" checkbox. Click "OK" and change the series color.

[image]

**Step 6.** Add a column of data that starts at 0.5 and increments by 1. Set these as the Series X values for the blue line. Add another three columns of data as shown below.

[image]

**Step 7.** Add a new series to the chart. Select the "x-Axis X" data for the Series X values and the "x-Axis Y" data for the Series Y values and click "OK" twice. Turn on the secondary horizontal axis.

[image]

**Step 8.** Select the newly created series, and add data labels to the left.

[image]

**Step 9.** Right-click the data labels and select "Format Data Labels". Under "LABEL OPTIONS. "Check Value From Cells" and select the x-Axis Labels data. Click "OK" then uncheck "Y Value" and "Show Leader Lines" back in "LABEL OPTIONS".

[image]

**Step 10.** Clean up. Select the x-Axis series and turn off the line and markers. Set the secondary horizontal and vertical axis labels to "None" (Format Axis > AXIS OPTIONS > LABELS).